# How can I grab the value of an input form on React Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I am attempting to grab the value of an input form on React Bootstrap but the obvious way doesn't seem to be working.

This is the form field component:

```
const FormField = ({
  type,
  label,
  value,
  onChange,
  controlId,
  placeholder,
}) => (
  <Form.Group as={Row} controlId={controlId}>
    <Form.Label column sm={4}>
      {label}
    </Form.Label>
    <Col sm={8}>
      <Form.Control
        type={type}
        value={value}
        onChange={() => onChange(value)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </Col>
  </Form.Group>
);
```

And here is the parent where I call that component above:

```
class FormFieldsGroup extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
  };

  render() { 
   const { firstName } = this.state;
   return (
        <FormField
          type="text"
          label="First Name"
          controlId="firstName"
          placeholder="First Name"
          value={firstName}
          onChange={firstName => this.setState({ firstName })}
        />
   )
  }
}
```

It only returns an empty string.

What can I do to store the value of that input in a local component state?

Answer (score 0):

```
value={firstName}
```

must be

```
value={this.state.firstName}
```

because your value is changing when you type

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post. I am using destructuring assigment. `const { firstName } = this.state;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try **onChange={onChange}** in Form.Control instead of   onChange={() => onChange(value)}
Also check whether it returns value direct or it returns event if returning event use event.target.value